amaranth - combinational cycle detected
I have for example the following json.
{
            "logicOperator": "and",
            "operation": [
                {
                    "name": "i1",
                    "operator": ">",
                    "value": 2
                },
                {
                    "name": "i2",
                    "operator": ">",
                    "value": 1
                }
            ]
        }

I would like to check if the condition is fulfilled or not.
For this, I generated the following lists for the hardware part.



index
0
1
2




result_indices1
-1
-1
0


result_indices1
-1
-1
1


operators
>
>
and


results
1
1
1



In Amaranth, I implemented it as follows:
def __init__(self, config):

   self.results = Array(Signal(1) for _ in range(len(config[index])))


def elaborate(self, platform):

   for index, element in enumerate(self.index):
       ...
        m.d.comb += self.results[index].eq(
                    self.results[self.result_indices1[index]] & self.results[self.result_indices2[index]])   


Unfortunately, I encountered an error: "Combinational cycle detected." I believe this is caused by self.results.
I’m now looking for a solution based on combinational logic that can be applied to a generic JSON structure. Does anyone have any advice or ideas on how to solve this?

Where are you expecting your inputs to come from?  I'm not familiar with the library you're using, but you appear to be taking all inputs from results[-1], which is the same thing as results[2] given a 3-element array - and that's your final output, so this is indeed a cycle.

I got the inputs from a stream
